# Create Dockerfile for ros2 package : ament_cmake error

Tags: ros2, tutorial, colcon, docker, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to use docker to develop ros2 packages.
In this context, I use the minimal_publisher package from https://github.com/ros2/examples as example which has the structure:

```
minimal_publisher/
minimal_publisher/CMakeLists.txt
minimal_publisher/lambda.cpp
minimal_publisher/member_function.cpp
minimal_publisher/not_composable.cpp
minimal_publisher/package.xml
minimal_publisher/README.md
minimal_publisher/Dockerfile #THIS FILE WAS ADDED BY ME
```

You can find the complete minimum example package on https://github.com/DentOpt/minimal_publisher

"minimal_publisher/Dockerfile" is the following dockerfile that I added to use to colcon build the package in a ros2 workspace in a docker container:

```
FROM ros:crystal
# install ros build tools
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3-colcon-common-extensions \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# clone ros package repo
ENV ROS2_WS  /home/ros2_ws
RUN mkdir -p ${ROS2_WS}/src/minimal_publisher
COPY ./ ${ROS2_WS}/src/minimal_publisher
# build repo
RUN cd ${ROS2_WS} \
    && colcon build \
    && source ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.bash
CMD ["bash"]
```

However, this leads unfortunately to the strange error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package): By not providing "Findament_cmake.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"ament_cmake", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake" with any of the following names:

ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
ament_cmake-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ament_cmake_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "ament_cmake" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

If I remove the building process manually from the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:crystal
# install ros build tools
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3-colcon-common-extensions \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# clone ros package repo
ENV ROS2_WS  /home/ros2_ws
RUN mkdir -p ${ROS2_WS}/src/minimal_publisher
COPY ./ ${ROS2_WS}/src/minimal_publisher
CMD ["bash"]
```

and run a docker container of the image, I can execute

```
cd ${ROS2_WS} \
        && colcon build \
        && source ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.bash
```

without any error and the package builds perfectly?!
Do you have any idea what could be the issue?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319610/create-dockerfile-for-ros2-package-:-ament_cmake-error/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2019-03-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you didn't source your ROS installation before running your build.

If you change:

```
RUN cd ${ROS2_WS} \
    && colcon build \
    && source ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.bash
```

to

```
RUN cd ${ROS2_WS} \
    && . /opt/ros/crystal/setup.sh \
    && colcon build \
    && source ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.bash
```

I would expect it to work.

> and run a docker container of the image, I can execute

When you enter a container, you enter via the entrypoint and the ROS docker images source the workspace in the entrypoint

HTH,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-03-27**:
You are completely correct, I thought ros is already sourced in the ros:crystal image.
I also found that for the source command additional dependencies are necessary.
So the complete setup can be changed to:

```
RUN cd ${ROS2_WS} \
    && . /opt/ros/crystal/setup.sh \
    && colcon build \
    && . ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.sh
```

and it works! Thanks a lot

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-03-27**:
Glad it worked!

> I also found that for the source command additional dependencies are necessary.

:+1:
`source` is a `bash` command. As dockerfiles are based on `sh` and not `bash`, it is better to use `.` instead of `source` (and the `setup.sh` files instead of the `setup.bash`)

> I thought ros is already sourced in the ros:crystal image

sourcing in Dockerfiles has no lasting effect as each RUN command runs in its' own context. So the sourcing needs to happen in the entrypoint.
For the same reason, the last line of your sample will also have no effect on the following layers or the resulting container.

```
&& . ${ROS2_WS}/install/setup.sh
```